# Using sass breakpoint with Prepros

Tags: css, sass, breakpoints, compass, prepros

Is there any way to use

> "[breakpoint](http://breakpoint-sass.com/)"

for sass within

> "Prepros"

?

Answer (score 0):

you can write your breakpoints in different file and can name that file as "_breakpoint.scss"

In your main app.scss you can call you dependent file with import function. So in your app.scss you would write :-

app.scss
@import "_breakpoint.scss";

now you can use breakpoint in this file which you have define in _breakpoint.scss file.

Hope its clear!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Here's an example:

```
@mixin breakpoint($point) {
    @if $point == xs {
        @media (min-width: 420px) { @content; }
    } @else if $point == sm {
        @media (min-width: 640px) { @content; }
    } @else if $point == md {
        @media (min-width: 960px)  { @content; }
    }
}
```

...specifying as many as you want. And then using breakpoints is as easy as this:

```
.my-class {
    color: red;

    @include breakpoint(md) {
        color: blue;
    }

}
```

In this example `.my-class` colour will be red, unless the viewport is at least 960px wide, in which case `.my-class` colour will be blue.

I hope this helps.